# How do i creat a column in power bi that is the z-score of another column?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

this is the formula that was give and it does not work
('titanic'[Age]-average('titanic'[Age]))/STDEV.P('titanic'[Age])
when i enter the average it auto corrects into list.average and the same thing for STDEV.P turns into list.standarddeviation

I tried a school tutor and he could not help because he has not used Power BI
I feel like i am missing something